# ttk.Button returns None

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am trying to use the invoke method of a ttk.Button, as shown at [TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#button) (look at *"The Command Callback"*), but I keep getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'invoke'

So, I tried this in the Interactive Shell:

```
ActivePython 3.1.1.2 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 3.1.1 (r311:74480, Aug 17 2009, 12:30:13) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32

>>> from tkinter import *
>>> import tkinter.ttk as ttk
>>> root = Tk()
>>> button = ttk.Button(root, text="Test").grid(row=0, column=0)
>>> print(button)
None
```

Which shows that ttk.Button returns None.

Is ttk.Button meant to return None. And, if so, why does TkDocs say that there is an invoke method?

Comment: For the record, this also happens for non-ttk widgets, and if you use `pack` instead of `grid`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you're entirely wrong: your code does **not** show that `ttk.Button` returns `None` -- it shows that the `grid` method on the button object returns `None`!  Don't you see that you're calling `.grid` on whatever it is that `ttk.Button` returns (the button object), and it's the result of that **grid** call that you're assigning to "button"?!

So do it right instead...:

```
button = ttk.Button(root, text="Test")
button.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

now you can `print button` and of course the results will be very different!-)