# tkinter pack or grid or place bug

Tags: python, tkinter

I had a problem with `tkinter`. After several hours of research I found my bug, but don't understand why it happened.

If I write this snippet:

```
self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.frame_content, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
```

instead of this one:

```
self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self.frame_content, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
self.progressbar.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'start'
```

I understand the error, but I do not understand why it occurs. Could someone explain it to me please?

Comment: The canonical answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2034576/3001761

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs because `grid(row = 2, column = 2)` returns null by definition, i.e. its not a bug. Thus, in your first example, `self.progressbar` is null. This is not the case in your second example in which `self.progressbar` holds an instance of the `ttk.Progressbar()`. The same is for `pack()`, btw.

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation; I will look into this matter to better understand.